# Getting video with USB SPI from device with FTDI 

Tags: c#, java, video, usb, spi

I need to implement Device manager for some card with FTDI chip.
We are looking into JAVA or C#, and we need to use it for transferring vedio using SPI.
Do we need to use FTDI DLL for java or C#?
Can we encounter serious problems implementing this in java ?

Comment: Note that it is spelled neither java nor JAVA, buy Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the direct connection with the FTDI DLL using both Java and C#. For Java I have used [ftd2xxj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftd2xxj/), even contributed some extensions to that. Works very and seems actively being maintained. I switched to C# 2 years ago and I'm using the wrapper provided by FTDI [FTDI C# Wrapper](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp/FTD2XX_NET_1010.zip). This also works perfectly, and I would say using one of these libraries is the recommended way to connect to your device instead of using a serial port connection. You can tune a lot of things such as the latency on the USB port and packet buffer sizes and such. I can imagine this can come in handy with video.

The Java option is fully open-source and business friendly, the C# version is provided as is without any restrictions to redistribute etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that uses ftdi. The solution I selected is to use a C DLL and call the c routines with JNI.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the libftdi/libusb approach if you want a more open source approach.  I'm not to sure what interfaces to these exist for Java and c# though.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested multiple FTDI chips in C and C# to do USB to SPI/I2C from Windows.
For Video generally SPI with an extra pin called D/C (data command ) is what is supported by displays devices.

Here is a video with an [FT232H board + an OLED 128x64 display in SPI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i8_EFs_j0I)
I used the default ftdi windows C SPI library. The FT232H can deliver up to 3M byte/S in SPI in theory.

The device [Nusbio](http://www.Nusbio.net) (based on the FT232RL) also support I2C/SPI at a smaller transfer speed and works with [the OLED 128x64 display in SPI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sGbVCSbmgo).
Nusbio can deliver up to 20 K byte/S in SPI for display. The Nusbio library is written in C#.

I am currently experimenting with the [FT4222 chip in I2C or SPI](https://twitter.com/MadeInTheUSB/status/809077322670292992) using the FTDI C library on top of which I wrote a C# library.  The FT4222 can deliver up to 500 K byte/S.

In conclusion you have to pick your chip and if your OS target is Windows C + C#
would be my advice. FTDI does not provide a lot of support/samples for C#, but that is what I do.